# Angular-Material: style mat-icon element differently, using css, based on icon type

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Throughout my code I use several icons from the Angular Material library.

Can I apply different css styles to them, based on their real type ?

Ex: I need the *folder* to have a different colour, and I need to do this only in a certain css theme, so I need to obtain this by applying a custom css style.

I tried something like:

```
 <mat-icon class="mat-icon-folder">folder</mat-icon>
```

and then

```
.mat-icon#mat-icon-folder {
    color: #FFDA6B;
}
```

or

```
.mat-icon-folder {
    color: #FFDA6B;
}
```

in my css file, but with no success.

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Learn more about css selectors here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp - This should give you a general idea as to why your selectors aren't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to apply styling on your icon. You can check this online [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-colden-5vqce?file=/src/app/app.component.css:0-269), and here are some references to help you to write valid CSS.

- [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```
/* by tag name */
mat-icon {
  color: red;
}

/* by class selector */
.mat-icon-folder {
  color: #ffda6b;
}

/* by tag name and class selector */
mat-icon.mat-icon-folder {
  color: blue;
}

/* by tag name and id selector */
mat-icon#folder-icon {
  color: purple;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. Just for my info, using the example from you, how could I make that icon yellow (2nd entry from the css file, "/* by class selector */") ? I could not get that to work...

Comment: It will work if you removed the other styles